# Scipy curve_fit multiple series of data, needing a unique set of fitting parameters for several curves

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, nonlinear-optimization

I will try to explain this as well as possible. I want to fit a non-linear function that minimizes the distance to 2 other curves.

[This picture explains this better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paajH.png)

I want to modify the orange curve (let's say "damage" it), by multiplying it by a highly non-linear function. As you can see, the fitted curve is the green one, and I have no problem for now.

The function to minimize has this shape:

```
def func_to_minimize(input_X, c1, c2, c3):
   xdata, orange_points_in_y = input_X
   damage = non_linear_function(xdata, c1, c2, c3)
   return np.multiply(damage, orange_points_in_y)
```

So, applying a curve_fit this way, I get the proper c1, c2 and c3 parameters to get the green curve between the two red ones:

```
(c1,c2,c3), pcov = curve_fit(func_to_minimize, (xdata, orange_points_in_y), ydata)
green_y_points = np.multiply(non_linear_function(xdata, c1, c2, c3), orange_points_in_y)
```

As I have multiple datasets (2 curves with same x values but different y ones), I am stacking the data into a 1D array:

```
xdata = np.concatenate((xdata,xdata))
ydata = np.concatenate((ydata_1,ydata_2))
orange_points_in_y = np.concatenate((orange_points_in_y, orange_points_in_y))
```

The problem arises because I have more than 1 curves like these (more than 1 "zone"), but all of them need to be fitted with a unique set of c1,c2,c3 parameters at the same time. You will understand it better with a new image:

[Problematic fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kelF.png)

In this image you can see the lime curve, which is obtained by getting 2 sets of parameters (one for each zone). But when I try to fit everything at the same time, I get the dark green curve, which is clearly incorrect. To feed the curve_fit I am concatenating all the data as before at the same time, making sure that all points correspond to each other as they should.

If anyone has any idea of how can I get this unique set of parameters, even with other algorithm, I would be very grateful. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatenating `ydata_1` and `ydata_2` you need to stack them vertically (you can use `np.vstack`). Loop through the rows of this vertically stacked array to obtain `ydata_1` and `ydata_2` and execute `curve_fit` within the loop to obtain the values of `c1, c2, c3` parameters separately for each `ydata_i`.

Comment: But I don't need to fit `ydata_1` and  `ydata_2` separatelly, I need to minimize the distance to both `ydata_1` and  `ydata_2` curves, as I did in the second image with the lime curve or in the first image. But being `c1, c2 and c3` the unique set of parameters that minimize this distances in all the "zones" (in the second image the red curves are the first zone and the blue ones the second).

I know that I won't get a perfect fit, but I was hoping I could do it better...